# Why is not Subject.next () emission detected in Angular template with async pipe?

Tags: angular, async-pipe

There is following code and I am wondering **why** `Subject.next(1)` emmision is not visible in template whereas `BehaviorSubject.next()` emission is visible.

I know that wrapping it inside `setTimeout()` fixes it, but I would like to understand it.

I seems, like `Subject.next()` is *synchronnous* and `async` pipe does not receive / mark for check.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>Subj: {{ subj$ | async }}</div>
    <div>BehavSubj: {{ behavSubj$ | async }} </div>
    <div>Interval: {{ interval$ | async }} </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  subj$ = new Subject<number>();
  behavSubj$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
  interval$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(100));

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subj$.next(1);
    this.behavSubj$.next(2);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-crnfgc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Read about Subjects. They dont emit the last emitted value to late subscribers. You async pipe subscription is made after the next call

Comment: It's not detected because it's to early. Replace all occurrences of `OnInit` with `AfterViewInit` and it works.

Comment: A BehaviorSubject has _replay_ behaviour, the vanilla Subject doesn't.

Comment: I have not realized, that it is timing issue ‍♂️, thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not detected because it's to early. Replace all occurrences of `OnInit` with `AfterViewInit` and it works.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, interval, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { take } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <div>Subj: {{ subj$ | async }}</div>
    <div>BehavSubj: {{ behavSubj$ | async }}</div>
    <div>Subj: {{ subj2$ | async }}</div>
    <div>BehavSubj: {{ behavSubj2$ | async }}</div>
    <div>Interval: {{ interval$ | async }}</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  subj$ = new Subject<number>();
  behavSubj$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
  subj2$ = new Subject<number>();
  behavSubj2$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
  interval$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(100));

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subj$.next(1);
    this.behavSubj$.next(2);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.subj2$.next(1);
    this.behavSubj2$.next(2);
  }
}
```

First you have to init the view so that the async pipe is already subscribed. Then you can send a value to a simple subject. A behavior subject is different. It stores its last value. You can first update a behavior subject and then subscribe. That's also the reason why you have to initialize a behavior subject but it makes no sense to initialize a basic subject.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-csfgvt?file=src/app/app.component.ts) is an example.

Comment: thank you so much! I spend two days for understanding my similar case

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the ReplaySubject instead of the Subject. Then even if you next into the subject, before the async pipe has subscribed to the observable, you get the previous nexted values.